# How to programmatically print coloured pdfs?

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I want to print some pdfs programmatically.

This code works and will print any pdf:

```cs
ProcessStartInfo psInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
psInfo.Verb = "Print"; // or "PrintTo"
psInfo.FileName = pdfFileName;
psInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/p /h \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", pdfFileName, printerName);
psInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
psInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
Process process = Process.Start(psInfo);
process.Close();
```

The problem:
I actually want to print coloured. Things like

> `PageSettings.Color`

won't work.

One solution could be, to set the settings of the network printer from grey to coloured, but actually I dont have the accessrights to change them with powershell or something like that.

So, I have some existing pdfs I want to print to print coloured.

There are some NuGet-packages, but i'm not allowed to use them.

The printer is able to print with colour!

Comment: Do you have colour printer? Have you tested printing using Windows Explorer Menu "Print" manually? Does it print colour?

Comment: @Sunil okey, well I should have written that. Yes of course